# rolling dice using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

simple beginner Java question. I just learned how to use arrays and it's still a little confusing to me. My goal is to simply roll a number of dice a number of times and then project it as a sum, frequency, and percentage. I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, but I'm overlooking it!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab1 {

private static int N = 0;
private static int M = 0;
private static int total = 0;
private static Random rnd = new Random();   

public Lab1(){

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    N = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dice would you like to roll?"));
    System.out.println("Dice: "+N);

    M = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to roll?"));
    System.out.println("Rolls: "+M);

    int total[] = new int[(6*Lab1.N)+1];

    for (int i=0; i<=total.length; i++)
        total[i] = 0;

    for (int roll=1; roll<=M; roll++){
        N = 1+rnd.nextInt(6);
        total[N]++;
    }

    System.out.printf("%3s%12s%12s\n", "Sum","Frequency", "Percentage " );

    for(int k=2; k<total.length; k++);{
        int percent = total[k]/(360);
        System.out.printf("%3s%12s%12s\n", k, total[k], percent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question, it's more of a "_here's what I want, do it for me_" scenario.

Comment: If you want any hope of an answer, please include your expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @Bfrank Side note: your first `for` loop where you're initializing each element of the array to zero is unnecessary. They're already zero, since you're using an array of primitive integers, as specified in the [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see the question is how can you store the previous roles of the dice. And I believe your problem is with this method:

```
for (int roll=1; roll<=M; roll++){
    N = 1+rnd.nextInt(6);
    total[N]++;
}
```

I would change this to

```
for (int roll=1; roll<=M; roll++){
    total[roll] = rnd.nextInt(6);
}
```

This will build up an array storing each dice roll - if that is of course what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int k=2; k<total.length; k++);{
```

You need to remove the `;` symbol from your loop as 'k' will not be resolved in the loop as you have terminated it. The format is `for(x, x, x) {`

The next thing to look at now is:

> Dice: 1
>
> Rolls: 1
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>       at Lab1.main(Lab1.java:26)

Hint:

```
total[i] = 0;   // this line is the problem.
```

Look at your `<=` in the loop.

```
    for (int i=0; i<total.length; i++)
```

Simply chaging it to `<`  results in this:

> Dice: 1
>
> Rolls: 1

Sum   Frequency Percentage

2           1           0

3           0           0

4           0           0

5           0           0

6           0           0

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, this loop will inevitably throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ("element" `total[total.length]` is out of bounds)

```
for (int i=0; i<=total.length; i++)
        total[i] = 0;
```

You should use `<` instead of `<=`.

```
for (int i=0; i<total.length; i++)
        total[i] = 0;
```

Second, this line here:

```
for(int k=2; k<total.length; k++);{
```

You have an empty loop here. You should remove the semicolon before the `{`:

```
for(int k=2; k<total.length; k++){
```

Now your code compiles, doesn't throw exceptions on the start, and prints a pretty table.
That's a start.